# Error al obtener la fecha de la bd

Tags: java

Mi problema es este: quiero que al darle a un **botón** me inserte la **fecha** que le pongo, o que al modificar la fecha y darle al botón me la inserte pero he probado miles de maneras y no funciona.

Os pongo el codigo..

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
/**
 *
 * @author jesus
 */
public class Principal extends javax.swing.JFrame {
 public static ConectaEmp tablaEmp;
 public Date date;
 public String Guardardate;
 public SimpleDateFormat format;

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public Principal() {
        format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        tablaEmp = new ConectaEmp();
        String sql = null;
        initComponents();
        try{
            tablaEmp.conecta();
            tablaEmp.crearSentencia();
            tablaEmp.ejecutarSentencia("select * from empleado");
            tablaEmp.irAlPrincipio();
            date = tablaEmp.rs.getDate("fechaAlta");
            fecha_alta1.setEnabled(false);
            jefe1.setEnabled(false);
            nombre1.setEnabled(false);
            num_dpto1.setEnabled(false);
            num_emp1.setEnabled(false);
            salario1.setEnabled(false);
            tarea1.setEnabled(false);
            fecha_alta2.setEnabled(false);
            jefe2.setEnabled(false);
            nombre2.setEnabled(false);
            num_dpto2.setEnabled(false);
            num_emp2.setEnabled(false);
            salario2.setEnabled(false);
            tarea2.setEnabled(false);
            printData(tablaEmp.rs);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void printData(ResultSet rs)throws SQLException {
        try{
        if(rs.getRow() != 0){
            fecha_alta.setText("");
            jefe.setText("");
            nombre.setText("");
            num_dpto.setText("");
            num_emp.setText("");
            salario.setText("");
            tarea.setText("");
            fecha_alta1.setText("" + rs.getString(date.toString()));
            jefe1.setText("" + rs.getDouble("jefe"));
            nombre1.setText(rs.getString("nombre"));
            num_dpto1.setText("" + rs.getDouble("num_dpto"));
            num_emp1.setText("" + rs.getDouble("num_emp"));
            salario1.setText("" + rs.getDouble("salario"));
            tarea1.setText(rs.getString("tarea"));
            fecha_alta2.setText("" + rs.getDate("fechaAlta"));
            jefe2.setText("" + rs.getDouble("jefe"));
            nombre2.setText(rs.getString("nombre"));
            num_dpto2.setText("" + rs.getDouble("num_dpto"));
            num_emp2.setText("" + rs.getDouble("num_emp"));
            salario2.setText("" + rs.getDouble("salario"));
            tarea2.setText(rs.getString("tarea"));

            Primero.setEnabled(!rs.isFirst());
            Anterior.setEnabled(!rs.isFirst());
            Siguiente.setEnabled(!rs.isLast());
            Ultimo.setEnabled(!rs.isLast());
            Primero1.setEnabled(!rs.isFirst());
            Anterior1.setEnabled(!rs.isFirst());
            Siguiente1.setEnabled(!rs.isLast());
            Ultimo1.setEnabled(!rs.isLast());
        }else{
            fecha_alta.setText("" + rs.getString(date.toString()));
            jefe.setText("" + rs.getDouble("jefe"));
            nombre.setText(rs.getString("nombre"));
            num_dpto.setText("" + rs.getDouble("num_dpto"));
            num_emp.setText("" + rs.getDouble("num_emp"));
            salario.setText("" + rs.getDouble("salario"));
            tarea.setText(rs.getString("tarea"));
            fecha_alta1.setText("");
            jefe1.setText("");
            nombre1.setText("");
            num_dpto1.setText("");
            num_emp1.setText("");
            salario1.setText("");
            tarea1.setText("");
            fecha_alta2.setText("");
            jefe2.setText("");
            nombre2.setText("");
            num_dpto2.setText("");
            num_emp2.setText("");
            salario2.setText("");
            tarea2.setText("");

            Primero.setEnabled(false);
            Anterior.setEnabled(false);
            Siguiente.setEnabled(false);
            Ultimo.setEnabled(false);
            Primero1.setEnabled(false);
            Anterior1.setEnabled(false);
            Siguiente1.setEnabled(false);
            Ultimo1.setEnabled(false);

            Eliminar.setEnabled(false);
            Aceptar.setEnabled(false);
            Modificar.setEnabled(false);

        }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void botoneraNavegacionActivada(boolean estado){
        Primero.setEnabled(estado);
        Anterior.setEnabled(estado);
        Siguiente.setEnabled(estado);
        Ultimo.setEnabled(estado);
        Primero1.setEnabled(estado);
        Anterior1.setEnabled(estado);
        Siguiente1.setEnabled(estado);
        Ultimo1.setEnabled(estado);
    }

    private void botoneraAccionActivada(boolean estado){
        Aceptar.setEnabled(estado);
        Modificar.setEnabled(estado);
        Eliminar.setEnabled(estado);
    }


    private void Salir1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        this.dispose();
    }                                      

    private void Salir2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        this.dispose();
    }                                      

    private void Salir3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        this.dispose();
    }                                      

    private void Salir4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        this.dispose();
    }                                      

    private void Salir5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        this.dispose();
    }                                      

    private void ModificarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try{
            fecha_alta1.setEnabled(true);
            jefe1.setEnabled(true);
            nombre1.setEnabled(true);
            num_dpto1.setEnabled(true);
            num_emp1.setEnabled(true);
            salario1.setEnabled(true);
            tarea1.setEnabled(true);
            tablaEmp.nuevoRegistro = false;

            botoneraNavegacionActivada(true);
            botoneraAccionActivada(true);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }                                         

    private void AceptarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try{
            tablaEmp.insertar(fecha_alta1.getText(), jefe1.getText(), nombre1.getText(),num_dpto1.getText(),num_emp1.getText(),salario1.getText(),tarea1.getText());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }                                       

    private void AgregarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try{
            tablaEmp.insertar(((String)fecha_alta.getText()), jefe.getText(), nombre.getText(),num_dpto.getText(),num_emp.getText(),salario.getText(),tarea.getText());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Como veis incluso aunque castee el text field no me lo coje y no se que hacer ;-;

Comment: Típicamente copiar todo el código de tu programa y tirarlo aquí para que encontremos que está mal no es una buena forma de obtener ayuda. ¿Puedes proveer un ejemplo más conciso del problema en una forma que los demás podamos reproducir? Imagina que se lo estás explicando a un colega. Tú no vas y simplemente le dices, ahí está mi programa, encuéntrame lo que está mal, ¿cierto?

Comment: ¿Has ido depurando lo elementos de tu programa: la conexión, la consulta, los resultados que trae en general, los resultados que trae en particular? Empieza por ahí, para que vayas determinando por ti mismo el posible problema. Es difícil poder ayudarte si no muestras ningún esfuerzo por encontrar el problema, otra cosa sería si plantearas la pregunta diciendo: *he probado tal y tal cosa, este dato lo recibo bien, pero este lo he depurado y no me trae nada, he probado la consulta en la base de datos directamente y me trae los datos bien, etc, etc, etc.*

Comment: A ver he probado a convertir el date a String y nada, lo he probado al reves poniendo la fecha como String y tampoco, obviamente no os he tirado el codigo para que resolvais mi problema entero, solo me fallan los botones de insertar y aceptar que me dan como error que no pueden convertir de date a String y viceversa, cuando cambio que coja la fecha como String me dice que no se puede pasar de double a String y me quede como.... "Si no te estoy pasando un double" en fin mi duda es que no se como hacer que funcionen los botones lo dicho he probado el parse y el format de la clase simpleFormat...

Comment: Os pongo donde falla y siento que os haya parecido eso, al contrario, solo necesito ayuda en esa parte es mi primera vez posteando aqui esta clase de errores y no sabia como iba la cosa

Answer (score 0):

```
fecha_alta1.setText("" + rs.getString(date.toString()));

fecha_alta.setText("" + rs.getString(date.toString()));

private void AceptarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try{
            tablaEmp.insertar(((String)fecha_alta1.getText()), jefe1.getText(), nombre1.getText(),num_dpto1.getText(),num_emp1.getText(),salario1.getText(),tarea1.getText());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }  



private void AgregarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try{
        tablaEmp.insertar(((String)fecha_alta.getText()), jefe.getText(), nombre.getText(),num_dpto.getText(),num_emp.getText(),salario.getText(),tarea.getText());
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Aqui es donde me falla y no se que mas hacer

Comment: Ahora ya me va, era un error en el que no me fije, pero ahora me salta otro y es que no detecta la fecha de la base de datos en la que estoy trabajando desde java me dice que no encuentra la fecha aunque si coge el valor..... no se a que es debido